# MVC 3 How to refresh only one Partial View from multiple Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

On my main screen I have two partial views. In first partial view I have ActionLink and image. How to refresh only second partialView after clicking on ActionLink which was on first partialView. I do not refresh first partialView as I do not make any changes in it. -Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

since you have not shared any code you can try wrapping your second partial inside a wrapper div e.g.

```
<div id="secondpartial">
  @RenderPartial("partialName")
</div>
```

lets assume that the link inside the first partial has an `id="firstPartialLink"`

```
<a href="#" id="firstPartialLink">Refresh Second Partial</a>
```

attach a click event handler to it

```
$(function(){
     $("#firstPartialLink").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      url:'@Url.Action("SecondPartialActionResult","Controller")',
      type:'GET'
      dataType:'html',
      success:function(data){
       $("#secondpartial").html(data);
      },
      error:function(jXhr){
         if(typeof console !='undefined')
           console.log(jXhr.responseText);
      }
     });
    });
});
```

the ActionResult would look like

```
public ActionResult SecondPartialActionResult(){

 return PartialView("viewname")
}
```

Comment: Actually the controller action would have to return a `PartialView("viewname")`

Comment: @XavierPoinas very right but i think returning the view would also do the job, though i have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery load to reload the second partial view

```
$(function(){

 $("#aLinkInFirstView").click(function(){

    $("#PartialViewDiv2").load(@Url.Action("action_for_second_view", "your_controller"));

   return false;
 });


});
```

Assuming **aLinkInFirstView** is the id of the anchor tag in your first PartialView and **PartialViewDiv2** is the div which holds the markup for the second partial view.

http://api.jquery.com/load/